# how to run selenium script from a bash file

Tags: python, bash, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have a windows laptop in which i have written a selenium script written in python which creates a github repository. It works fine when a run the python file but it gives error when i try to run the script from a bash file. what should i do

my bash file:

```bash
python3 login.py
```

my python file which i am calling from bash:

```py
def login():
    chr_options = Options()
    chr_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chr_options)

    driver.get('https://github.com/new')
```

this is what i get when i try to run the python file with bash from my ubuntu terminal and i have a windows machine and the python file works fine when i try to run it from the windows terminal

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binaryStacktrace:#0 0x55de662442a3
 <unknown>#1 0x55de66002f77 
<unknown>#2 0x55de66029047
 <unknown>#3 0x55de660277d0 <unknown>#4 0x55de660680b7 <unknown>#5 0x55de66067a5f <unknown>#6 0x55de6605f903 <unknown>#7 0x55de66032ece <unknown>#8 0x55de66033fde <unknown>#9 0x55de6629463e <unknown>#10 0x55de66297b79 <unknown>#11 0x55de6627a89e <unknown>#12 0x55de66298a83 <unknown>#13 0x55de6626d505 <unknown>#14 0x55de662b9ca8 <unknown>#15 0x55de662b9e36 <unknown>#16 0x55de662d5333 <unknown>#17 0x7f87539e4b43 <unknown>
```

i have a windows 10 laptop in which my selenium script works fine, but when i run the file through the bash terminal it gives this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55de662442a3 <unknown>
#1 0x55de66002f77 <unknown>
#2 0x55de66029047 <unknown>
#3 0x55de660277d0 <unknown>
#4 0x55de660680b7 <unknown>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the python file in windows it uses Chrome installed in you Windows machine, but when you work in a bash terminal you do it on a Linux machine that runs as a virtual machine in you Windows.
So it is a separate machine and it cannot use Chrome from your Windows. It needs to have its own Chrome. Additionally this virtual machine does not have a GUI so you will need to run selenium in the `headless` mode.